# Is Hibernate entity callback methods are only called by using EntityManager

Tags: hibernate, callback, entity

I used Spring's HibernateTemplate to save entity, I also add call back method like this

```
@PrePersist
  public void prePersist() {
    setCreateDate(new Date());
  }
```

but I found this callback annotation was not called when I called saveOrUpdate() method.

```
  public void persist(Object entity) {
    hibernateDaoSupport.getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(entity);
  }
```

I found some post said that only use EntityManager will call these callback annotation method, is it right? If not, why my @PrePersist not being called.
Could anybody give me a direction to investigate the problem, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, EntityManager event listener methods are only invoked if you're using EntityManager. You should be using [JPA template](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/orm.html#orm-jpa-template) instead of HibernateTemplate within Spring if you want to use JPA instead of raw Hibernate.

Comment: Is there a Hibernate equivalent to `@PrePersist` that can be used with the `HibernateTemplate`?